# C# string function not returning a value

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with this function.

```
public static string artnetReceiver()
{
    string dataout;
    List<string> dmxString = new List<string>();
    byte[] _dmxData = new byte[511];

    artnet.NewPacket += (object sender, ArtNet.Sockets.NewPacketEventArgs<ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetPacket> e) =>
    {
        if (e.Packet.OpCode == ArtNet.Enums.ArtNetOpCodes.Dmx)
        {
            var packet = e.Packet as ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetDmxPacket;
            Console.Clear();

            if (packet.DmxData != _dmxData)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < packet.DmxData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (packet.DmxData[i] != 0)
                    {
                    }

                    int temp = i + 1;
                    string chanNum = temp.ToString();
                    string chanValue = packet.DmxData[i].ToString();

                    dmxString.Add(chanNum + "-" + chanValue);
                };

                //dmx stuff

                dataout = string.Join(",", dmxString.ToArray());
                dmxOut = dataout;
                //Console.WriteLine(dataout);//works here

                _dmxData = packet.DmxData;
            }
        }
    };
    return dataout; // doesn't work
}
```

For whatever reason the string i build won't get to the return portion however when I use `Console.WriteLine(dataout);` further up in the function it spits out to console but if i call it thru the function else where like for example, `Console.WriteLine(artnetReceiver());` I get a blank result.
EDIT new code

```
public static void artnetReceiver()
        {  
               artnet.NewPacket += OnArtNet_NewPacket;  
        }

       public static string ProcessDataOut(string dataout)
       {
            return dataout;
       }

        /*public static void getDMXPackets()
        {
            artnetReceiver((val) =>
            {
                return val;
            });

        }*/

        public static void OnArtNet_NewPacket(object sender, ArtNet.Sockets.NewPacketEventArgs<ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetPacket> e)
        {
            byte[] _dmxData = new byte[511];
            List<string> dmxString = new List<string>();
            string dataout; //included here so the sample will compile
            if (e.Packet.OpCode == ArtNet.Enums.ArtNetOpCodes.Dmx)
            {
                var packet = e.Packet as ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetDmxPacket;
                Console.Clear();

                if (packet.DmxData != _dmxData)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < packet.DmxData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (packet.DmxData[i] != 0)
                        {
                        }

                        int temp = i + 1;
                        string chanNum = temp.ToString();
                        string chanValue = packet.DmxData[i].ToString();

                        dmxString.Add(chanNum + "-" + chanValue);
                    };

                    //dmx stuff

                    dataout = string.Join(",", dmxString.ToArray());
                    dmxOut = dataout;
                    _dmxData = packet.DmxData;
                    ProcessDataOut(dataout);
                }
            }
        }


        byte[] _dmxData = new byte[511];
```

Okay the problem i'm struggling with now is actually later on in my code calling say for example `artnetReceiver()` and when it runs it returns the string value so i can export send it as a packet string like so `mstrResponse = "Data: " + artnetReceiver();`

Comment: Side note: Unless you are stuck on old version of .Net use `async`/`await` instead - it seem to be better match of your expectation of how asynchronous code should behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of having basically a duplicate answer to MichaC's one, here's my explanation for why you are observing this behaviour, with a possibly simpler solution.

This code

```
artnet.NewPacket += (object sender, ArtNet.Sockets.NewPacketEventArgs<ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetPacket> e) =>{
 //code omitted
}
```

is saying "When artnet raises the NewPacket event at some point in the future, execute the code between { and }."

So nothing actually happens when this code is encountered first except that the runtime remembers to come back when `artnet.NewPacket` occurs, and execute the code.

So with that in mind, when you execute `artnetReceiver`, the sequence of events is more or less this

1. You declare `dataout` with no value.
2. You tell the runtime to execute some code when `artnet.NewPacket` occurs sometime in the future. This code incidentally is in the form of an anonymous delegate, which is basically a self-contained void function that has no return value.
3. You then return `dataout`, which is of course blank.
4. Later, the `artnet.NewPacket` event occurs, and the delegate is executed, but crucially, w*hen the last closing brace defining the delegate is encountered, the runtime jumps out of this delegate method, it does not continue on to step 3 again!*  That's because from the perspective of the runtime, the delegate isn't part of the function that defined it, so it's treated as a totally standalone method.

Perhaps this will make it clearer; let's move the event handler delegate into a  separate method of its own, defined outside of `artnetReceiver`:

```
public static string artnetReceiver()
{
    string dataout;
    List<string> dmxString = new List<string>();
    byte[] _dmxData = new byte[511];
    artnet.NewPacket += OnArtNet_NewPacket;
    return dataout; // doesn't work
}
```

And the event handler is

```
//note the return type - it's void!
public void OnArtNet_NewPacket(object sender, ArtNet.Sockets.NewPacketEventArgs<ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetPacket> e)
{
string dataout; //included here so the sample will compile
if (e.Packet.OpCode == ArtNet.Enums.ArtNetOpCodes.Dmx)
        {
            var packet = e.Packet as ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetDmxPacket;
            Console.Clear();

            if (packet.DmxData != _dmxData)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < packet.DmxData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (packet.DmxData[i] != 0)
                    {
                    }

                    int temp = i + 1;
                    string chanNum = temp.ToString();
                    string chanValue = packet.DmxData[i].ToString();

                    dmxString.Add(chanNum + "-" + chanValue);
                };

                //dmx stuff

                dataout = string.Join(",", dmxString.ToArray());
                dmxOut = dataout;
                //Console.WriteLine(dataout);//works here

                _dmxData = packet.DmxData;
            }
        }
}
```

So as you can clearly see, nothing actually gets executed when you assign the event handler to the event, it's only when the even fires that the code is executed.

So in terms of the solution - whatever you need to do with `dataout`, must be initiated from inside the event handler. The simplest way to do this will be if you can encapsulate whatever the next step of your process is within a method contained in the same class as `artnetReceiver` - let's say you call it `ProcessDataOut(string dataout)`.
Then you simply modify the event handler so that the last thing it does it call that method, passing `dataout`:

```
_dmxData = packet.DmxData;
ProcessDataOut(dataout);
}
```

> Note: The ProcessDataOut method can't have a return type (well, it can
>   but it's pointless, since there is nothing there to receive the
>   returned value). Therefore whatever you need to do with dataout, you
>   need to do it inside the ProcessDataOut method. This is just how
>   asynchronous/event-driven code works :)

However the more elegant (and more flexible) solution is to use a callback delegate (Action or Func) as indicated in MichaC's answer, but the same concept applies; this delegate can't return anything and has to do the "next step" of whatever process you are trying to implement.

The implications of this are that you may very well need to invert your application logic; that is to say that rather than having something waiting on the "outside" for `artnetReceiver` to return something (which it never will) you need to move that something *inside* artnetReceiver's `ProcessDataOut` method.

Comment: I'm updating my code in the OP to reflect your changes. I believe i'm close but i'm really struggling with this.

Comment: Ok, don't panic :) Update your question with the aspects that you are struggling with, and we'll try to resolve it!

Comment: @AlexBloom - ok I see the problem here, you can't ever return `dataout`. When the event handler method executes `ProcessDataOut` there is nothing waiting for any return value. Whatever process you need to do with `dataout`, needs to be inside the `ProcessDataOut` method itself, does that make sense? I'll update the answer to clarify this

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/3375141 can you look at line 182. This is where I'm trying to get that data to. I'm not entire sure how to accomplish this now this is way above my head now all of this encapsulation.

Comment: Ok. Consider this. What if you moved the code currently in `SocketHelper`, inside the `ProcessDataOut` method? That's ultimately what you need to do; whether you just copy-paste or pass the `SocketHelper` instance to the `MainClass` constructor (or maybe even new one up in `MainClass`) is a design call you need to make :)

Comment: You've been a great help. I'm still kinda stuck but I'm going to attempt to work thru this.

Comment: Don't forget you can keep updating the question, and we'll keep trying to get you up and running :)

Answer (score 3):

That's an event handler you have there in your method, this runs asynchronously to your method invocation.
You cannot expect to return a variable set within the event handle.

Store the value somewhere else in a global scope, or use for example a callback Action to return you the value

Example usage of `Action<T>`

```
public static void AnotherFunction()
{
    ArtnetReceiver((val) =>
    {
        // do work with the value returned
    });
}

public static void ArtnetReceiver(Action<string> callback)
{
    artnet.NewPacket += (object sender, ArtNet.Sockets.NewPacketEventArgs<ArtNet.Packets.ArtNetPacket> e) =>
    {
        // some stuff going on...

        var dataout = value;
        callback(dataout);
    };
}
```

Comment: So how would I go about doing that then making it the global scope right after my main class in my namespace then? I apologize i'm rather new to C#

Comment: Global scope is generally pretty bad because you don't know when your variable would be set or change. I'd say you would have to invert your call chain. Whatever you do after returning the string, must run after the event got called and your variable is set. So, you might have to stick to callbacks and pass in a Func<string> to artnetReceiver which you call  within your event handle

Comment: It's clear to me i'm trying to do advanced things here that I haven't done before in C#. If you could demonstrate the proper use of Func<string> with my code I provided in the OP that'd be awesome. I've been struggling with this for about 3 hours now and finally gave up and posted to stack.

Comment: so I did the call back portion in the code like you had advised now, i'm running into the issue of returning the val `public static void getDMXPackets()
        {
            artnetReceiver((val) =>
            {
                return val;
            });
           
        } ` this doesn't work I get an error about an anonymous function or something like that.

Comment: That's not going to work ;) You have to put your logic into the callback body.